# What will happen to rails app if I delete rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rvm, rbenv, bash

I'm working on making my first very simple rails app, and I think I'm running into trouble because I have both rvm and rbenv installed.

I'm not actually sure if it's related to that, but I thought it might be --

I'm trying to run the command: `sudo rake gems:install`
and I'm getting this error message:

```
Could not find rake-11.1.1 in any of the sources
```

I ran bundle update rake and bundle install, and when I write 'which rake' - I get this: (which is why I thought it might be related to the fact that I have both rvm and rbenv included in my bash_profile)

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rake
```

If this is the issue --- what will happen if I uninstall rvm? I don't really understand what it does well enough to understand what it will do to my existing code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rvm is a great toolset for managing multiple ruby versions. I think of it like a tackle box for fishing: [image: ruby tackle] You've got different ruby versions, 1.9.3, 2.0.0, 2.2.3, etc. like the layers on the tackle box. rvm keeps a different directory for each version of ruby you have installed.

If you `rvm use 2.2.3` you're telling your shell to point to `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby` (check `which ruby` to be sure).

If you `rvm use system` and then `which ruby` you'll see `/usr/local/bin/ruby`, or the system-installed version

You can put different gems (tackle/bait/tools) in each one. This is immensely useful if you're developing on multiple ruby apps/gems at the same time.

If you `rvm implode` you'll clean all the .rvm/ruby installs out of your system. This is a good, safe way to keep your system ruby untainted, which is more of a hassle to reinstall.

Go ahead and try reinstalling rvm and bundle-installing.